# Split data into two training and one test sets

Tags: r, testing, split, training-data

How can we split data int two training sets and one testing set using R?

I tried this, but I want to split train into two training sets:

```
set.seed(770)
sample <- sample.int(n = nrow(datazoo), size = floor(0.75*nrow(datazoo)), replace = F)
train <- datazoo[sample, ]
test  <- datazoo[-sample, ]
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not do the sample split again on *train*, replacing *datazoo*? Or split in half by `nrow`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach illustrated on iris data which has 150 rows

```
data(iris)
```

sample for first train set from all the row indexes:

```
t1 <- sample(1:nrow(iris), size = floor(0.4 * nrow(iris)))
```

sample  for second train set from row indexes not sampled in t1:

```
t2 <- sample(setdiff(1:nrow(iris), t1), size = floor(0.4 * nrow(iris)))
```

everything that remains is in t3:

```
t3 <- setdiff(1:nrow(iris), c(t1,t2))
```

is it true:

```
any(t1 %in% t2)
any(t1 %in% t3)
any(t2 %in% t3)
```

or you can use

```
library(caret)
```

split data to one train and test set

```
t1 <- createDataPartition(iris$Species, p = 0.8)
```

split the t1 train set to two train sets:

```
t2 <- createDataPartition(iris$Species[t1$Resample1], p = 0.5)

t3 <- setdiff(t1, t2)
```

define the test set:

```
t4 <- setdiff(1:nrow(iris), c(t2, t3))
```

the second approach is preferred since `createDataPartition` makes a stratified split if splitting based on a factor variable and splits based on percentiles if a numeric variable is given.